# How to stop all processing running in background without killing in this context?

Tags: bash, background-process, shortcut, kill-process

My bash script named `n_commands.sh` is of the form

```
command1 &
command2 &
..........
commandn &
```

When I run `bash n_commands.sh` on the terminal then all the commands are running in the background.

When I try to stop all the n processes that are using the resources, I need to kill each process separately. Is there any way to stop all the background processes that are running due to the command `bash n_commands.sh` instantly without killing them manually?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/kill-all-background-jobs the one works for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609300/209955

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pkill` to kill all children of the current process.

```
trap "pkill -P $$" SIGINT  #intercept ^C

#if foreground ends before background jobs, the output below is 
#an argument for a pkill  -P arg comand.
echo $$    

command1 &
command2 &
..........
commandn &

...

pkill -P $p   #if you need to end bg jobs on exit.
```

Comment: Would you put the `pkill` command in a `trap` statement that runs when the script process receives a signal?

Answer (score 0):

After you start all the background processes, have the main script wait for them to finish. Then you can kill the entire process group of the main script, and all the child processes will be killed as well.

```
command1 &
command2 &
..........
commandn &
wait
```

After you start this, if you type <kbd>Control-c</kbd> it will kill all the commands.

Comment: It is not happening. The processes are still running.

Comment: I can't get this to work either.  Trying with some `sleep 30 &` then `wait`.  I can run the script in my terminal, then use `ps` to see the sleep commands still running after Ctrl-C

Comment: Sorry, I thought I tested it, but I must have waited too long and the sleeps finished.

Comment: `^C` kills the waiting process, not the processes it waits for.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I thought it sent to the foreground process group. Since non-interactive shells don't have job control, the background processes would be in the same process group.